# C++ Increase int size limit

Tags: c++, int, size, max

Is there a way in C++ to increase the limit on integers? I want to work with a 13 digit number e.g. 4823423658586. The complier does not allow this.

Comment: Have you tried using `long long`? What does the compiler not allow?

Comment: Reag e.g. [this reference of the basic types available in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: You can inspect what's the biggest number you can represent with a standard type like [`std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Comment: Thats the limit of 64 bits.  You can write your own library or look at this duplicate entry [Is there a library or other way to do 128-bit math operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604271/is-there-a-library-or-other-way-to-do-128-bit-math-operations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the largest 13 digit integer can be stored using 6 bytes you need a type which will store at least 6 bytes, that type is a long long which can hold 8 bytes.

So instead of

```
int x=100;
```

use

```
long long x=100;
```

Comment: Or better yet, `int_fast64_t x = 100;`.  I don't think `long long` is specified in the C++ standard, and if it is, it may not be guaranteed to be 64 bits.

Comment: @AndrewHenle 64 bits is indeed guaranteed: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: Aaah, it appears to be new in C++11.  Good to know.

Comment: C++11 isn't always guaranteed though so I may end up using `int_fast64_t` myself sometimes.